# Monotone subsequences in a sequence of $n^2+1$ distinct real numbers

Tags: combinatorics

**Theorem:** Every sequence of $n^2 + 1$ distinct real numbers contains a subsequence of length $n + 1$ that is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.

So for $n = 3$ here is a sequence of $3 \times 3 + 1 = 10$ distinct integer numbers(since integers are real as well).

```
1 10 2 9 3 8 4 7 5 6
```

According to theorem there must be a sequence of $3 + 1 = 4$ length that is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. I now list all the $4$ length 
sub-sequences.

```
1 10 2 9

10 2 9 3

2 9 3 8

9 3 8 4

3 8 4 7

8 4 7 5

4 7 5 6
```

I am unable to find any of them to be strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.

Does it means that theorem is false?

Comment: Subsequences can skip elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many more subsequences of length $4$ than just those you have listed. All of yours consist of *consecutive* elements of the original sequence, but it is also allowed for a subsequence to skip elements.

Answer (score 0):

A subsequence doesn't mean that the terms have to be consecutive, just in the same order.

Your sequence contains the increasing subsequence 1,2,3,4,5,6.

(And the theorem is indeed true.)